# Send money with Paypal

Tags: grails, paypal

In the web app im developing, should be a "give me my money" button, that takes the amount of money the user has in his/her balance (inside the web), and transfer that money into his/her paypal account. Ive searching the documentation, in google, and here in stackoverflow, and found nothing specifically for Grails, that is what im using. Don't know if that's even possible.

Any link i can follow? any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, you're looking to transfer funds to a receiver's PayPal account?
Have a look at [Adaptive Payments (Send money)](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro) or [Mass Pay](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_batch-payment-overview-outside)

Note: You have to contact PayPal Customer Service to get the MassPay API enabled on your account.
If you're not eligible for MassPay, or you wish to use the Adaptive Payments API's, you'll need to register your application via https://www.x.com/ and get an Application ID.

Answer (score 0):

There's no Grails plugin for this (yet) but adding the functionality you want is easy enough using [Paypal's Website Payments Standard](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics)

Comment: Im searching there, but i can only see things for accept payments. Ill keep searching. Thank you!