# Is it possible to send money from my own paypal account to an email address using adaptive payments

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a node.js web application which at times needs to send a user money knowing only their email address. This is essentially the same thing as PayPal's [send money](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/send-money-online) interface, but needs to be programatically executed.

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736269/send-money-with-paypal) which suggest using their newer Adaptive Payments API to do this, however nowhere in the docs or examples do I see how to send money from my account to an email address.

Is my only option to dive into the [MassPay](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_masspay) API which paypal is moving away from?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Adaptive Payments Implicit simple payments -

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APCallsHeadersAndPaymentTypes/

Comment: I looked over that API and couldn't find where to do it. It seemed the API call required a manual approval step done in a browser.

Comment: You only need the manual approval by the sender in the browser if your api credentials don't belong to the sender and if the senderEmail field in your PAY request doesn't equal that of your api account.